# Color Profile strategies for developing web sites with sRGB photos and Monitor RGB comps

Tags: css, rgb, srgb

**Overview**

I'm looking for advice / solutions on standardizing color profiles on comps so colors of HTML/CSS gradients/blends match effects achieved in a comp.  I often get PSDs using the **sRGB color profile** so when I color pick something to recreate a gradient / icon / or background the HEX color and resulting CSS/HTML gradient does not match the original sRGB gradient provided in the comp. Typically I just discard the embedded color profile for a **Monitor RGB** color profile that better matches PSD colors to end result CSS colors. Here's an [example](http://www.gballard.net/psd/go_live_page_profile/embeddedJPEGprofiles.html) showing differences between color profiles.

**Details**

So here's the predicament: A designer wants to standardize PSDs to use an embedded sRGB color profile because exported images (JPEG / PNG) retain that sRGB color profile to display correctly when loaded in a browser. So photos / textures / things that I can't recreate in CSS will export as JPEG/PNG with the better sRGB profile (which is an understandable request).

As a front-end developer I often **recreate** elements displayed in a comp using CSS and HTML (no images) and this requires me to match HEX colors properly between what's in the PSD and what's rendered on the website. So, I would prefer to standardize with a **Monitor RGB color profile** so that everyone uses something closer to what's actually rendered in the browser.

Just curious how everyone else approaches this problem?  There's often cases where I use a mixture of CSS and PNGs to achieve an effect (especially effects that need to change dynamically (size/hue/shading...) so exporting an image with sRGB and overlaying it with CSS gradients / shadows ends up being a mixture of sRGB / Monitor RBG and hence subtly different from the comp.

**Answer Format**

Hopefully I've properly asked this question - suitable answers would just give a perspective on how you deal with the problem - OR (better) if theres an SCSS sRGB() function or some other algorithm to convert an RGB / HEX color to sRGB then I will throw it into a SASS mixin.

Comment: awesome article on the subject from @xtine http://www.viget.com/inspire/the-mysterious-save-for-web-color-shift/

Comment: - should point out that this article is 5 years old

Comment: Another blog on the subject http://bjango.com/articles/photoshop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how we ensure color consistency in Photoshop: correct color-picking and consistency in saved-for-web images.

### Setting Up Photoshop Color Space

The first thing we all have to do is to ensure we are working under the correct color profiles. To do this follow these steps:

- Go to `Edit > Color Settings` or `Shift + Command + K` or `Shift + Control + K` in windows.
- From the `Settings` drop down select `North America Web/Internet`
- Commit your changes by hitting `OK`.
- Go to `View > Proof Setup` and select `Internet Standard RGB (sRGB)`
- Hit `Command + Y` or `Control + Y` in windows to enable `Proof Colors`, alternatively you can just go to `View > Proof Colors`

### Exporting (Save for Web)

- When exporting via Save for Web ensure that `Convert to sRGB` is checked.

You are done, you should now enjoy color accuracy across all of your files and in HTML and images will be ensured to display consistently across devices and browsers.